# Position of ActiveX control in a Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

I have a Word document with multiple tables. Inside each table, there are multiple ActiveX controls - labels.

I would like to loop through all the labels and find their position in the table so I can reference the name of the table and the column header to use it in another part of the code.

Other way to do it would be to loop through all the cells in all tables and check if there is a label inside (and check its name).

However I cannot find solution to any of these two options.

This thread unfortunately does not help: [word vba: get position of an ActiveX control within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934194/word-vba-get-position-of-an-activex-control-within-a-table)

The code below gets me the caption of every label.

```
Dim fld As Field
For Each fld In ThisDocument.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.OLEFormat.Object.Caption
Next
```

However, I didn't find a way to get its position (ideally the table cell).

EDIT: I went through all properties in fld and fld.OLEFormat.Object, but didn't find anything.

Comment: So, what code did you try, and exactly what isn't working? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: examine the `fld` object in the _Watch window_. one of the properties may be what you need. ... maybe examine `fld.OLEFormat.Object`, so that you don't have to go through the `fld` object properties tree to get to it

Comment: I did that. You can see that there is nothing in the OLEFormat.Object - [See here](http://www.janhorcicka.com/files/object.JPG). I also went through the whole fld and didnt find anything there either. That's why I am asking.